# How/Where to customize the snippet for a Dart class?

Tags: dart

I used to be able to modify the snippet for a Dart class editing `.vscode/extensions/dart-code.dart-code-X.YY.Z/snippets/dart.json`, but since some recent versions (VSCode? Flutter? Dart?) my customized snippet is not being taken into account, the default snippet for a Dart class only.

How/Where to customize the snippet for a Dart class?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't added another dart/flutter extension that provides a same-named snippet?  I've had collisions before.

Comment: I have *Dart* and *Dart Data Class Generator* extensions only for *Dart*, and *Awesome Flutter Snippets*, *Flutter* and *Flutter Color* extensions for Flutter. *Dart Data Class Generator* was added recently but the problem existed already.